# masstransit - consumers are no registered and activated

Tags: autofac, masstransit

I'm trying to register consumers but no success using mass transit.
I registered MT using Autofac using module approach.

Firstly - I created some simple message:

```
public class SimpleMessage
{
    public string msg { get; set; } 
}
```

and I've managed to send them into queue:

```
var endpointTest = await _busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:queueTest"));
await endpointTest.Send(new SimpleMessage
{
    msg = "test"
});
```

Then I created a consumer:

```
public class SimpleMessageConsumer : IConsumer<SimpleMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public SimpleMessageConsumer(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SimpleMessage> context)
    {
        _logger.Info($"got msg from queue: {context.Message}");
    }
}
```

But it won't run when the message appeared in the queue. My configuration is:

```
public class BusModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<BusSettings>().As<IBusSettings>();

        builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumer<SimpleMessageConsumer, SimpleMessageConsumerDefinition>();

            cfg.Builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var busSettings = context.Resolve<IBusSettings>();
                var logger = context.Resolve < ILogger >();
                var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(bus =>
                {
                    bus.AutoDelete = busSettings.AutoDelete;
                    bus.Durable = busSettings.Durable;
                    bus.Exclusive = busSettings.Exclusive;
                    bus.ExchangeType = busSettings.Type;

                    //bus.UseNServiceBusJsonSerializer();

                    bus.Host(busSettings.HostAddress, busSettings.Port, busSettings.VirtualHost, null, h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(busSettings.Username);
                        h.Password(busSettings.Password);
                    });

                    bus.ReceiveEndpoint("queueTest", ec =>
                    {
                        ec.Consumer(() => new SimpleMessageConsumer(logger));
                    });
                });

                return busControl;

            }).SingleInstance().As<IBusControl>().As<IBus>();
        });
    }
}
```

in program.cs
I have:

```
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

and

```
containerBuilder.RegisterModule<BusModule>();
```

Such I mentioned - sending a msg to queue works but consumer wasn't running.

Can you help me what did I do wrong? how should I fix the configuration? in order to activate the consumer?

Comment: What do you mean it's not running? Have you looked at RMQ management UI and see the exchange for your receive endpoint? If it's there, does it have any consumers? I personally have no idea why you'd use Autofac for a new .NET app, so the registrations might get messed up. MassTransit hosted service expects IBus and other things to be registered in the Microsoft DI container, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: That's an old application which was migrated to core few days ago. (actually, some components(microservices) have been working on .net framework still).
I see exchange but consumer won't run (it won't "catch" a message and won't handle it)
so it looks like consumer didn't connect into queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your configuration to work properly, using the actual bus configuration methods instead of mixing the two solutions:

```
public class BusModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<BusSettings>().As<IBusSettings>();

        builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumer<SimpleMessageConsumer, SimpleMessageConsumerDefinition>();

            cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
            {
                var busSettings = context.GetRequiredService<IBusSettings>();
                var logger = context.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();

                //bus.UseNServiceBusJsonSerializer();

                bus.Host(busSettings.HostAddress, busSettings.Port, busSettings.VirtualHost, null, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(busSettings.Username);
                    h.Password(busSettings.Password);
                });

                bus.ReceiveEndpoint("queueTest", ec =>
                {
                    // i'm guessing these apply to the receive endpoint, not the bus endpoint

                    ec.AutoDelete = busSettings.AutoDelete;
                    ec.Durable = busSettings.Durable;
                    ec.Exclusive = busSettings.Exclusive;
                    ec.ExchangeType = busSettings.Type;

                    ec.ConfigureConsumer<SimpleMessageConsumer>(context);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: that probably works. (probably because I got an exception from autofac and I am trying to figure out):
 ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(
 Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory, Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Diagnostics.
 HealthChecks.HealthCheckServiceOptions], Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Diagnostics.HealthChecks.
 DefaultHealthCheckService])' on type 'DefaultHealthCheckService'.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Duplicate health checks were registered with the name(s): masstransit-bus (Parameter 'registrations')

Comment: Ignore it please. everything works. Just too many hours looking into configuration and I didn't notice my obvious mistake

Comment: @BartoszKowalczyk Could you please describe what was your problem? I'm facing the same problem: Duplicate health checks were registered with the name(s): masstransit-bus

Comment: I do not remember now. Sorry.
I believe I had twice AddMassTransitHostedService with no arguments as a result It tried to register 2 HealthChecks with the same name